# syntax error, unexpected token "}" on PHP

Tags: php

Sorry if its something simple I'm just missing but I'm quite new to PHP and don't understand why I'm getting a `syntax error, unexpected token "}"` on lines 4, 5 and 6. Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    echo "It works";
}

else {
    header("location: ../signup.php")
}
```

Comment: Missing `;` after `header(...)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a ; at the end on heard();

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        echo "It works";
    }
    
    else {
        header("location: ../signup.php");
    }
    ?>
```